# How do I concatenate String and an output evaluated from a function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Basically, I have the following say:

```
counter <- 3
k <- 9999
```

I would like to get R to print the following:

```
on the 3rd count: 9999
```

Does anyone what command should I use to do this? Please spell it out for me ,as I am completely new to R.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The basic construction is

```
paste("on the ", counter, "rd count: ", k, sep="")
```

You'll have to be a little clever to choose the right suffix for the digit (i.e. "rd" after 3, "th" after 4-9, etc. Here's a function to do it:

```
suffixSelector <- function(x) {
  if (x%%10==1) {
    suffixSelector <- "st"
  } else if(x%%10==2) {
    suffixSelector <- "nd"
  } else if(x%%10==3) {
    suffixSelector <- "rd"
  } else {
    suffixSelector <- "th"
  }
```

}

Thus:

```
suffix <- suffixSelector(counter)
paste("on the ", counter, suffix, " count: ", k, sep="")
```

You need to set the `sep` argument because by default `paste` inserts a blank space in between strings.

Comment: Doesn't work too well with 13, for instance... This is a little more complicated than it seems! (Also, you need to make sure your posted code actually returns the chosen `suffixSelector`!)

Comment: can the paste function be put into the while loop ? Because I dont know why nothing gets printed out when the paste thingy is in the while loop ???

Comment: Depends... can you paste your loop, so we can see the full code?

Comment: Dont worry. I was being stupid. I thought the paste function does encompass the function of print as well. Apparently, it only concatenates, but doesnt print. So i have to do print(paste(......)). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Use `sprintf`

```
> sprintf("on the %drd count: %d", counter, k)
[1] "on the 3rd count: 9999"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach to hooking each integer up with it's appropriate suffix. If you pick it apart, you'll see that it does capture the syntactical(?) rule for constructing the ordinal form of every integer.

```
suffixPicker <- function(x) {
    suffix <- c("st", "nd", "rd", rep("th", 17))
    suffix[((x-1) %% 10 + 1) + 10*(((x %% 100) %/% 10) == 1)]
}

## Testing with your example
counter <- 3
k <- 9999
paste("on the ", paste0(counter, suffixPicker(counter)), 
      " count: ", k, sep="")
# [1] "on the 3rd count: 9999"

## Show that it also works for a range of numbers
x <- 1:24
paste0(x, suffixPicker(x))
#  [1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th"
# [11] "11th" "12th" "13th" "14th" "15th" "16th" "17th" "18th" "19th" "20th"
# [21] "21st" "22nd" "23rd" "24th"
```

One explanatory note: The `10*(((x %% 100) %/% 10) == 1)` bit is needed to pick out numbers ending in 10 to 19 (11, 12, and 13 are the real bad actors here) sending them all to elements of `suffix` containing `"th"`.